# Errors building ncurses 6 in AIX 64 with gcc

Tags: aix, ncurses

The `configure` command issued errors when called with the default settings (like as with the 64 bits flags). But the built libncurses worked in both versions (32 and 64 bits).

Should I worry about this error ?

**Default settings:**

```
configure && make clean && make
```

**With 64 bit flags (-X64 necessary to AIX `ar` command, and -maix64 to `gcc`):**

```
ARFLAGS="-X64" CFLAGS="-maix64" CXXFLAGS="-maix64" configure && make clean && make
```

**The full `configure` output with default settings:**

```
checking for egrep... grep -E
Configuring NCURSES 6.0 ABI 6 (Wed Oct 26 14:34:30  2016)
checking for package version... 6.0
checking for package patch date... 20150808
checking build system type... error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.3.0
checking host system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.3.0
checking target system type... powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.3.0
Configuring for aix7.1.3.0
checking for prefix... /usr/local
checking for gnatgcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for executable suffix... 
checking for object suffix... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking version of gcc... 4.8.3
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking $CC variable... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for ldconfig... no
checking if you want to ensure bool is consistent with C++... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking if g++ works... yes
checking for g++... /opt/freeware/newbin/g++
checking version of /opt/freeware/newbin/g++... 4.8.3
checking if you want to build C++ binding and demo... yes
checking if you want to build with Ada95... yes
checking if you want to install terminal database... yes
checking if you want to install manpages... yes
checking if you want to build programs such as tic... yes
checking if you want to build test-programs... yes
checking if you wish to install curses.h... yes
checking for mawk... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking for egrep... (cached) grep -E
checking for a BSD compatible install... /opt/freeware/newbin/install -c
checking for tdlint... no
checking for lint... lint
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking if ln -s -f options work... yes
checking for long file names... yes
checking if you want to use pkg-config... yes
checking for pkg-config... /opt/freeware/newbin/pkg-config
checking for /opt/freeware/newbin/pkg-config library directory... checking done... /opt/freeware/lib/pkgconfig
checking if we should install .pc files for /opt/freeware/newbin/pkg-config... no
checking if we should assume mixed-case filenames... auto
checking if filesystem supports mixed-case filenames... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for exctags... no
checking for ctags... ctags
checking for exetags... no
checking for etags... no
checking for ctags... yes
checking for etags... no
checking for makeflags variable... 
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ld... ld
checking for ar... ar
checking for nm... nm
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for options to update archives... -curv
checking if you have specified an install-prefix... 
checking if libtool -version-number should be used... yes
checking if you want to build libraries with libtool... no
checking if you want to build shared libraries... no
checking if you want to build static libraries... yes
checking if you want to build debug libraries... yes
checking if you want to build profiling libraries... no
checking for specified models...  normal debug
checking for default model... normal
checking if you want to have a library-prefix... auto
checking for PATH separator... :
checking if you want to build a separate terminfo library... no
checking if you want to build a separate tic library... no
checking if you want to link with the GPM mouse library... maybe
checking for gpm.h... no
checking for default loader flags... 
checking for an rpath option... 
checking if release/abi version should be used for shared libs... auto
checking which gcc option to use... -fPIC
checking if you want to disable library suffixes... no
checking if you wish to append extra suffix to header/library paths... 
checking if you wish to install ncurses overwriting curses... no
checking if external terminfo-database is used... yes
checking which terminfo source-file will be installed... ${top_srcdir}/misc/terminfo.src
checking whether to use hashed database instead of directory/tree... no
checking for list of fallback descriptions... 
checking if you want modern xterm or antique... xterm-new
checking if xterm backspace sends BS or DEL... BS
checking for list of terminfo directories... /usr/local/share/terminfo
checking for default terminfo directory... /usr/local/share/terminfo
checking if big-core option selected... yes
checking if big-strings option selected... yes
checking if you want termcap-fallback support... no
checking if ~/.terminfo is wanted... yes
checking if you want to use restricted environment when running as root... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for unlink... yes
checking if link/symlink functions work...  link symlink
checking if tic should use symbolic links... no
checking if tic should use hard links... yes
checking if you want broken-linker support code... no
checking if tputs should process BSD-style prefix padding... no
checking if _XOPEN_SOURCE really is set... yes
checking if SIGWINCH is defined... yes
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking if you want wide-character code... no
checking whether to enable _LP64 definition in curses.h... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... 1
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking whether to use struct dirent64... no
checking if you want tparm not to use X/Open fixed-parameter list... yes
checking for type of bool... auto
checking for alternate terminal capabilities file... Caps
checking for type of chtype... uint32_t
checking for type of ospeed... short
checking for type of mmask_t... uint32_t
checking for size CCHARW_MAX... 5
checking for type of tparm args... intptr_t
checking if RCS identifiers should be compiled-in... no
checking format of man-pages... normal
checking for manpage renaming... no
checking if manpage aliases will be installed... yes
checking if manpage symlinks should be used... yes
checking for manpage tbl... no
checking if you want to build with function extensions... yes
checking if you want to build with SCREEN extensions... yes
checking if you want to build with terminal-driver... no
checking for extended use of const keyword... yes
checking if you want to use extended colors... yes
configure: WARNING: This option applies only to wide-character library
checking if you want to use extended mouse encoding... yes
checking if you want to use extended putwin/screendump... yes
checking if you want $NCURSES_NO_PADDING code... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for signed char... yes
checking size of signed char... 1
checking if you want to use signed Boolean array in term.h... no
checking if you want SIGWINCH handler... yes
checking if you want user-definable terminal capabilities like termcap... yes
checking if you want all development code... no
checking if you want hard-tabs code... no
checking if you want limited support for xmc... no
checking if you do not want to assume colors are white-on-black... yes
checking if you want hashmap scrolling-optimization code... yes
checking if you want colorfgbg code... no
checking if you want interop bindings... yes
checking if you want to link with the pthread library... no
checking if you want reentrant code... no
checking if you want experimental safe-sprintf code... no
checking if you want wgetch-events code... no
checking if you want to see long compiling messages... yes
checking if you want to see compiler warnings... 
configure: checking for gcc __attribute__ directives...
... scanf
... printf
... unused
... noreturn
checking if you want to work around bogus compiler/loader warnings... no
checking if you want to enable runtime assertions... no
checking if you want to use dmalloc for testing... no
checking if you want to use dbmalloc for testing... no
checking if you want to use valgrind for testing... no
checking if you want to perform memory-leak testing... no
checking whether to add trace feature to all models... no
checking if we want to use GNAT projects... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking if -lm needed for math functions... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for opendir in -ldir... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for regcomp... yes
checking for regular-expression headers... regex.h
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for getopt.h... no
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/bsdtypes.h... no
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for ttyent.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for getopt.h... (cached) no
checking for header declaring getopt variables... stdio.h
checking if sys/time.h works with sys/select.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking if gcc supports options to tune inlining... yes
checking for signal global datatype... volatile sig_atomic_t
checking if unsigned literals are legal... yes
checking if external errno is declared... yes
checking if external errno exists... yes
checking if data-only library module links... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getegid... yes
checking for geteuid... yes
checking for getopt... yes
checking for getttynam... no
checking for issetugid... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for remove... (cached) yes
checking for select... yes
checking for setbuf... yes
checking for setbuffer... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigvec... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for times... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for isascii... yes
checking whether sigaction needs _POSIX_SOURCE... no
checking if nanosleep really works... yes
checking for termio.h... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking whether termios.h needs _POSIX_SOURCE... no
checking for tcgetattr... yes
checking for vsscanf function or workaround... vsscanf
checking for working mkstemp... yes
checking whether setvbuf arguments are reversed... no
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for type sigaction_t... no
checking declaration of size-change... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking if poll really works... yes
checking for va_copy... yes
checking for __va_copy... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... (cached) yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for openpty in -lutil... no
checking for openpty header... no
checking if we should include stdbool.h... yes
checking for builtin bool type... no
checking for library stdc++... no
checking whether /opt/freeware/newbin/g++ understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /opt/freeware/newbin/g++ -E
checking for typeinfo... yes
checking for iostream... yes
checking if iostream uses std-namespace... yes
checking if we should include stdbool.h... (cached) yes
checking for builtin bool type... yes
checking for size of bool... unsigned char
checking for special defines needed for etip.h...  
checking if /opt/freeware/newbin/g++ accepts parameter initialization... no
checking if /opt/freeware/newbin/g++ accepts static_cast... yes
checking for gnatmake... no
checking for library subsets... ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs
checking default library suffix... 
checking default library-dependency suffix... .a
checking default object directory... objects
checking c++ library-dependency suffix... .a
checking if linker supports switching between static/dynamic... no
checking where we will install curses.h... ${prefix}/include/ncurses
checking for src modules... ncurses progs panel menu form
checking for tic... /usr/bin/tic
checking for defines to add to ncurses6-config script...  -D_ALL_SOURCE
package: ncurses
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating include/MKterm.h.awk
config.status: creating include/curses.head
config.status: creating include/ncurses_dll.h
config.status: creating include/termcap.h
config.status: creating include/unctrl.h
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating ncurses/Makefile
config.status: creating progs/Makefile
config.status: creating panel/Makefile
config.status: creating menu/Makefile
config.status: creating form/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating misc/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/Makefile
config.status: creating misc/run_tic.sh
config.status: creating misc/ncurses-config
config.status: creating man/ncurses6-config.1
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating include/ncurses_cfg.h
Appending rules for normal model (ncurses: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (ncurses: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (progs: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (progs: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (panel: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (panel: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (menu: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (menu: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (form: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (form: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (test: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (test: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (c++: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for debug model (c++: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+ext_funcs)
creating headers.sh

** Configuration summary for NCURSES 6.0 20150808:

       extended funcs: yes
       xterm terminfo: xterm-new

        bin directory: /usr/local/bin
        lib directory: /usr/local/lib
    include directory: /usr/local/include/ncurses
        man directory: /usr/local/share/man
   terminfo directory: /usr/local/share/terminfo
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a bug-reporting system.  The problem would be clearer by looking in `config.log`

Comment: Sorry. I cannot know if it's a bug or settings for an untypical environment/platform.

Comment: Like most programs, there's a [place to report bugs](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#report_bugs).

Answer (score 2):

After the new install of `rpm.rte` we might see the error like this

```
error: incorrect format: unknown tag" if AIX level is not same as or higher than
   AIX 61 TL9 SP6
   AIX 71 TL4
   AIX 72

   This error is from the lslpp command due to the INSTALLPREFIX tag deprecation and use of new INSTPREFIXES tag in newer rpm.
   This issue has been addressed and fixed in AIX version mentioned above.
```

https://m.ibm.com/https/public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/README-yum

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from something *outside* ncurses's configure script, and the only clues I've found are related to rpm queries, e.g., [IC92045: RHEL 6 RPM TAG "INSTALLPREFIX" WAS REPLACED BY "INSTPREFIXES" SO SCRIPTS REFERENCING THE OLD TAG WILL FAIL](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC92045)

It's likely that something in your shell initialization is calling a script which misbehaves with an rpm query.

Comment: The isolated point where the message is shown is in `config.guess` at command: `/usr/bin/lslpp -Lqc bos.rte.libc` (the full command: `/usr/bin/lslpp -Lqc bos.rte.libc | awk -F: '{ print $3 }' | sed s/[0-9]*$/0/`. Although has message errors, the final result seems to succeeded. Messages were sent to stderr.

Comment: So, I guess that it can be ignored, and I can rely on the result of build. Right ? The next step will try to fix the generation of shared libraries, isn't working, maybe LDFLAGS or others settings. Any suggestions are welcome.